# Pattern Validator in Angular Reactive Forms using Regex

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

My requirement is to add an Angular reactive-form pattern validator that produces an error "Name is invalid" when the form control "name" contains the keyword "**user**" (case-insensitive)

**Here is my form group**

```
new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/user/i')]),
      userType: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    })
```

**HTML Part**

```
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              id="name"
              aria-describedby="yourName"
              formControlName="name"
            />

              <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="testForm.get('name').hasError('required')  && testForm.get('name').touched">
                Name is required
              </div>
              <div class="error-msg" *ngIf="testForm.get('name').errors?.pattern  && testForm.get('name').touched">
                Name is invalid 
              </div>
```

I researched multiple answers on the stack with more or less similar context but can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Validators.pattern(/user/i)`

Comment: All you need to update your regex and it will work `Validators.pattern('^((?!user).)*$')` here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-akqflh?